# convertAndSend cannot be cast back when listener gets the message

Tags: java, jackson, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to send messages to a queue and in a consumer I get it, but I cannot cast it.

When I send it, I do this.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myExchange", "binding", MyObject);
```

`MyObject` is a custom objected created in that project. In another project, I created `MyObject.class` exactly the same (but I know the object signature is not the same).

The converted set for my listener is the following.

```
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper());

    return messageConverter;
}

private ClassMapper classMapper() {
    DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
    classMapper.setDefaultType(MyObject.class);
    return classMapper;
}
```

So, at my listener, the following code doesn't work. I've noticed the body comes with `[B@1232(byte[232]`.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(final Message message) {
    final MyObject myObject = (MyObject) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should be getting a `ClassCastException`. Is that right? Could you post the complete stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Put the MyObject class in a seperate jar.  Reference this new jar from both the sender and the recipient.

Additional Info
String is an object.
Convert your object to json (in a string) and pass the jsonString as the third parameter to convertAndSend.

In the recipient you should do something like this:

```
final String jsonString = (String) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
```

Comment: is there any way to dont have to share them?

Comment: not sure.  you could convert the object to json, then send json as the message (as a string) then on the other end, get the string and convert it from json to a locally defined, but with the same members class.

Comment: any example of how to do that?

Comment: example of what?  sending the json as a message?  implementing two classes that produce (and are produced from) the same json?

Comment: basically yeah, I am using convertAndSend... not sure how to do what you described.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you set the `MessageConverter` at the sender side to `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` if you want to consume the message at the receiver side as json.

```
Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = ...; // create and configure

rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("myExchange", "binding", MyObject);
```

Otherwise the [default `SimpleMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#setMessageConverter-org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter-) is used to send the message.

> The default converter is a SimpleMessageConverter, which is able to handle byte arrays, Strings, and Serializable Objects depending on the message content type header.

So I guess your `MyObject` is `Serializable` and the default `MessageConverter` serializes it to an byte array. As you said

> So, at my listener, the following code doesn't work. I've noticed the body comes with [B@1232(byte[232].